# hapi-sequelize 3.0.4 support for Hapi version 17.2.0

Tags: hapi.js

I am trying to use `hapi-sequelize` 3.0.4 with `hapi.js` 17.2.0 using the following configuration:

```
{
    plugin: require("hapi-sequelize"),
    options:[
      {
        name: "mysql", // identifier
    models: ["./plugins/sequelize/models/*.js"], // paths/globs to model files
    sequelize: new Sequelize(
      process.env.DB_NAME,
      process.env.DB_USER,
      process.env.DB_PASS,
      {
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: "mysql",
        port: process.env.DB_PORT ? parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT) : 3306
      }
    ), // sequelize instance
    sync: false, // sync models - default false
    forceSync: false // force sync (drops tables) - default false
  }
]
```

}

It gives the following error:

```
name[1] --missing---
```

Is this the latest version of `hapi-sequelize` compatible with `hapi.js` 17.2.0?

Comment: This plugin does not support Hapi v17.

Comment: If I were you I'd try migrating to use the sequelize library directly without relying on an out of date wrapper library.

Comment: thank you for the answer @NileshMali